# React.js code not recognized in TSX file (VS 2015 Update 1 RC)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with update 1 release candidate.  I can get React.js code and syntax highlighting to work inside a .JSX file, but nothing works inside a .TSX file.  To get the .jsx file to work, I just put these 3 lines in my default.aspx page.  I thought that update 1 for Visual Studio 2015 supported .tsx files?  What do I have to do to get them to work?

script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.2/react.min.js"
script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.2/react-dom.min.js">
script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you get started:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JSX